# How to Support JFrame transparency on Linux

Tags: swing, rounded-corners

I'm making a java swing application which is executed on linux machine and shown in users' computer by X11 forwarding.

I want to apply rounded corners on JFrame, so I changed its background to new Color(0,0,0,0).
The frame is now hidden on my computer(windows 10). But the linux(centOS7) doesn't seem not to support Window Frame transparency.

It returns error below.

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT translucency is not supported
    at java.awt.Window.setBackground(Window.java:3844)
    at java.awt.Frame.setBackground(Frame.java:988)
```

Without changing its background works fine on both but the default background is also shown.
Is there any way to make rounded corners??
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not every platfrom supports transparency.

Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

chapter
*Determining a Platform's Capabilities*

```
import static java.awt.GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency.*;

// Determine what the default GraphicsDevice can support.
GraphicsEnvironment ge =
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

boolean isUniformTranslucencySupported =
    gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(TRANSLUCENT);
boolean isPerPixelTranslucencySupported =
    gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT);
boolean isShapedWindowSupported =
    gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(PERPIXEL_TRANSPARENT);
```

To be tested, but I don't thing that X11 forwarding allows transparency !

**EDIT**
Just made a test, through ssh -X, java version  1.8.0_162-b12
and it works.
What is your java version ?

[image]

Comment: Via X11, returns false, false, and true. It means I cannot make the border conered, ehh? Please... I have to make it. I both tried java 6 and 8 but same.

Comment: You need at least Java 7. Try this example : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/ShapedWindowDemoProject/src/misc/ShapedWindowDemo.java.
BTW, I use Oracle's JVM, not OpenJDK's one